# google sheets (h)lookup last non-null value in specific column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to populate a column with the last known price at the end of a batch of orders.
Please see an example attached. [image]

I need the last price known from columns "price". Please note that there is not always value.
I tried something like this : =LOOKUP(B2:H2,"price",B3:H3<>"")
But it didn't really work.
(the nos 18 and 3 in column "I" are just examples. I need the green 3 results),thx.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: is there always 2 months? if so you can simply do =IF(G3<>"",C3,G3)

Comment: no, it's a lot of years and months, this is only an example

Comment: my comment on JvdV's answer should do the trick then.
If possible though, I'd seriously consider rebuilding the file. something simple would be to have that data on a seperate table with columns: Fruit, sku, month, piece, price
and then on a new sheet make those calculations. It will make your life alot easier down the line. But than that's not always possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(B3:H3,B$2:H$2="price"),COUNTIFS(B$2:H$2,"price",B3:H3,"<>"))
```

If there could be empty gaps in your data, try this alternative:

```
=INDEX(A3:H3,MAX(COLUMN(A3:H3)*(A$2:H$2="price")*(A3:H3<>"")))
```

Comment: the 1st works, but not when there are blanks involved, any idea on how to solve that? I tried adding something like: <>"" but didn't work.

Comment: Blanks? I went with your sample data. If things change or are different with real data, try to change your sample to represent your data @Tom. Not sure what you meant now.

Comment: I added a new screenshot, here you can see that for apples the F,G,H are empty and the formula doesn't consider C and gives no result

Comment: If I try that it gives me an error: "Error Array arguments to COUNTIFS are of different size." (maybe due to B2:F2 at the end, I tried B2:H2 at the end but still no result, see screenshots)

Comment: Can you share you GS? The `F2` was a typo. The formula works for me

Comment: @Jvd5 looks like an array formula. Not sure if google docs supports that.

Comment: Turns out it does, you simply need to wrap everything in a function "ArrayFormula". Try it like this:
=ArrayFormula(INDEX(FILTER(B3:H3,B2:H2="Price"),COUNTIFS(B2:H2,"Price",B2:H2,"<>")))

note: i'd also make sure that both "<>" and "=Price" conditions are in both places to avoid strange results

Comment: both not working, maybe a GS setting. Where can I share the GS, here?

Comment: @user13900375, it shouldn't be an arrayformula at all. I tried to build a sample in GS and it works just fine. Thanks for thinking along though

Comment: @Tom, you can share a link just here in a comment or so.

Comment: See my two formulas on your sheet @Tom

Comment: ok, figured it out, there was a couple other typos:
this one is working for me:
=ArrayFormula(INDEX(FILTER(B2:H2,(B$1:H$1="Price")*(B2:H2<>"")),1,COUNTIFS(B$1:H$1,"Price",B2:H2,"<>")))

Comment: @ user13900375, I tried your solution in a different sheet, and it works also, cool!